# how to send warning when run script using Start-Job

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How can I show a message to console when start script using Start-Job? I tried write-warning but don't work.

Example:

```
# On file script.ps1
#dumb code here
write-warning "Success!"
#end file
PS> Start-Job script.ps1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background jobs run in a separate PowerShell.exe process so the only way to get text from the background job code and display on the interactive console is to use `Receive-Job`.

In the background job code use `Write-Output "Success"`. `Start-Job script.ps1 | Wait-Job | Receive-Job` will display your message.